# Conflicts when including slack/list.h

Tags: c

I am trying to use the `slack/list.h` library however, when I try to include it in my header file I keep getting conflicts with `pthread.h`, which I am not directly using. Basically its saying that there are methods with the same names in `slack/locker.h` as there are in `pthread.h`. How can I use the `slack/list.h` library while avoiding these conflicts?

Comment: I looked in here http://libslack.org/sources/list.h nothing jumped out at me. What conflicts are you seeing?

Comment: Include the exact error messages.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to tell without the exact error message but it appears that [`locker.h`](http://libslack.org/sources/locker.h) defines certain things already defined by `pthread.h` under certain circumstances.

I'm talking specifically about the reader/writer locks which some implementations of PThreads did not support (Android API level 8 and less, for example).

Since the stuff in `locker.h` is inside conditional compilation controlled by `HAVE_PTHREAD_RWLOCK`, the *first* thing I'd try is compiling your code with that set correctly, such as:

```
gcc -DHAVE_PTHREAD_RWLOCK blah blah blah
```

That should stop it from trying to define the stuff already in `pthread.h`.